# looping an array of objects and getting data from outside iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array that looks the parentChildData array from my code example,

If the `nest:0` that means the data is parent, and if `nest:1` that means that data is a child of the last `nest:0` object.

I am wanting to loop over this object and use the index of that loop to pull some data from another array of objects, but we have a concept of open and closed parents, open means we need to collect the child data, and closed means we don't. We monitor what is open and closed by array that would look similar to this `["P000", "P003"]`

So what I am wanting to is,

```
const openRows = ["P000", "P0003"];
const newData = [];
const parentChildData = [
  [
    {
        "header": true
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000",
        "nest": 0,
        "expanded": true
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-002",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-003",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-001",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001-001",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001-002",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P002",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P002-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P003",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P003-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P003-001",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P004",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P004-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P005",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P005-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P006-000",
        "nest": 0
    }
]

parentChildData.forEach((row, index) => {
    if(index === 0 && row.header) {
       //we always want the header row
       newData.push(baseData[index]);
    }
    if(row.nest === 0) {
        //we always want the parent rows regardless of if they "open" or "closed"
        newData.push(row)
    }
    if(openRows.includes(row.pk)){
        //here we somehow need to check the next row of data in baseData and push it to newData, and then check the next row and push that, UNTIL we hit the next interation where row.nest == 0.
        //I have no idea how to do this.
    }
})
```

I basically cannot work out how to get rows of data and push them to my newData array if it's parent is open, and then stop that iteration when it hits the next parent (nest:0) in the loop?

For arguments sake the output of the above if it worked would look similar to this,

Comment: Kindly provide expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filtered out the parents along with their `childs` based on the `openRows` array by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) methods.

Demo **:**

```js
const openRows = ["P000", "P003"];
const parentChildData = [
  {
    "header": true
  },
  {
    "pk": "P000",
    "nest": 0,
    "expanded": true
  },
  {
    "pk": "P000-000",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P000-002",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P000-003",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P000-001",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P001",
    "nest": 0
  },
  {
    "pk": "P001-000",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P001-001",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P001-002",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P002",
    "nest": 0
  },
  {
    "pk": "P002-000",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P003",
    "nest": 0
  },
  {
    "pk": "P003-000",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P003-001",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P004",
    "nest": 0
  },
  {
    "pk": "P004-000",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P005",
    "nest": 0
  },
  {
    "pk": "P005-000",
    "nest": 1
  },
  {
    "pk": "P006-000",
    "nest": 0
  }
];

// Filtered parentChildData based on openRows.
const newData = parentChildData.filter(({ pk }) => openRows.includes(pk?.split('-')[0]));

console.log(newData);
```